# How to show columns data in Reportview bar charts

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping, ssrs-2008-r2

I need to show the data from a SQL query as shown below on bar chart by using SQL Reporting bar chart

[image]

Where I have to show the chart like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open the Toolbox and select the 'Chart' report item. Draw out the chart on your report, and 
select a 'Stacked Bar' within the 'Bar' chart types. Then, in the Chart Data window, add the last 4 columns as Sum Values and add the Risk Categories as a Category Group (if my assumption that you want to group by Risk Categories is correct). You will see them stack on top of each other, and from there you can change the look-and-feel of the graph.

This link is a tutorial on Stacked Column Charts (make sure you select the Stacked Bar, though) that will hopefully help you get started.

http://www.allaboutmssql.com/2013/08/ssrs-stacked-column-bar-chart.html